# Return a string in a function that doesn't receive args and returns a T | undefined value in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've this function in typescript:

```
get_value(): T | undefined {
   let TValue: T | undefined;   
   return TValue;
}
get_value() // result => undefined
```

The return can be type "T" and "undefined", in this case  the above function always returns undefined. How can I return a string value?. For instance, the below function gives an error if I want to return a string:

```
export abstract class NVap<T> {
 abstract get_value((): T | undefined;  
}

export class Vap<T> extends NVap<T> {

get_value(): T | undefined {
    let TAa: T | undefined; 
    //set a value string to the variable
    TAa = "some str";
    return TAa;
 }
}

let task = new Vap();
task.get_value();

// result => result =>  error TS2322: Type '"some str"' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `T`? Is `get_value` a member of some class?

Comment: yes, I've added more info!

Comment: How do you want `get_value` to behave? You defined it generic (so the return type depends on how it's instantiated), but you use it like it's a string. Does it always return a string?

Comment: `T` can be any type, e.g. number, and you can't assign a string to that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to compile, make get_value() return `T | string | undefined`

```
export abstract class NVap<T> {
  abstract get_value(): T | string | undefined;
}

export class Vap<T> extends NVap<T> {
  get_value(): T | string | undefined {
    let TAa: T | string | undefined;
    TAa = "test";
    return TAa;
  }
}

let task = new Vap<string>();
task.get_value();
```

This approach doesn't make much sense to me, at least without more context. If you are not using the generic type `T` and you assume that the return type will be a `string`, why not making the return type of get_value() `string | undefined`?

```
export class Vap<T> extends NVap<T> {
  get_value(): string | undefined {
    let TAa: string | undefined;
    TAa = "test";
    return TAa;
  }
}

let taskBoolean = new Vap<boolean>();
console.log(taskBoolean.get_value());

let task = new Vap();
console.log(task.get_value());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the specify which type has `T` when you declare Vap(). Otherwise, **`T` will be interpreted as undefined as well**.
Adding the type should do the work:

```
let task = new Vap<string>(); //If you want to retrieve a string
task.get_value(); // returns string | undefined
```

However, there is another problem in your code: you can't pass a string to a type T before declaring an object. This is because, when you specify a generic type, you have to define the type at "runtime".
To make it works a possible adjustment is:

```
export interface NVap<T> {
  get_value: () => T | undefined  
}

export class Vap<T> implements NVap<T> {

  value: T | undefined

  constructor(value: T | undefined){
    this.value=value
  }

  get_value(): T | undefined {
      return this.value;
  }
}

let task = new Vap<string>("Assign the string here");
task.get_value();
```

In this way, you define a pure class. However, if you need to update the value later, instead of passing it during construction, you can use a setter:

```
export class Vap2<T> implements NVap<T> {

  value: T | undefined

  set_value(value: T | undefined){
    this.value=value;
  }

  get_value(): T | undefined {
      return this.value;
  }
}

let task2 = new Vap2<string>();
task2.set_value("Assign here");
task2.get_value();
```

I leave you this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=19#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgOQDVMwAeAFQD44BvAKDjgHNgYB9AN0wBsBXYAFxwAFAEo4AXmrk4AHzi8kAE2DpkwJYzoBfOnVCRYcbN0wBnM3GJgAjBWoIAtmG7BHwFJaIl7tPYy4%20QTgZeUUVNSQNf2MIJDMYKF5sGGhhQP4hUIVlVXUlUXpGRhgACwQzADoM4AkahjhdBpZ2GrEsuRyI-L9i4qhWXigkODKK6p5%20AG4G3SaDaHgTc0trACZfJxc3Dxgva196BpqOsNzI6IazVk5J4HS70668qIKi4rGqmrq7mcYmxgtW5BdohTrhF4aXp9OADGBDEafCZBP6NHR6VzwGDmADWkjgUQA7lYSHYElBkExKMIAEQAQQsCCYiNKeHJlLgrIGNNEM0xo1xa3xRJJYA27KQVLEM2xZhxa0q11ad1pDLMTJGXOAPJlgsqQLavKAA) to check the solutions I have just shown and to experiment with them.

Comment: The problem is, that the OP tries to assign a string *inside* the class in the `get_value` method. Setting the type parameter for an instance doesn't fix this

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't solve the fix

Comment: @jga I have updated. I was missing the assignment of the string

Comment: @A_A I missed the string assignment, now it works